# How to reuse android device back button handler component from multiple classes using react native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

In my scenario, I am trying to use android back handler class in single file. How to access this from multiple class files instead of duplicating.

my code below

```
export default class hardware extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.BackButton = this.BackButton.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener'BackPress',this.BackButton);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('BackPress',this.BackButton);
  }

  BackButton() {
    if(this.props.navigation){
        this.props.navigation.goBack(null);
        return true;
      }
    }
}
```

How to access from multiple other class files screens?

```
export default class screenone extends Component {
   // how to access here?

}
```